# Asp MVC3 one to many Create and View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, many-to-many, partial-views, one-to-many

I can not figure out a way to create one to many model in a single view, any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model, include the "many".

Example

`public class Parent
{
   public int ParentId;
}`

public class Child
{
   public int ChildId;
   public int ParentId;
}

Then create a View Model

`public class ParentViewModel
{
Parent p;
IEnumerable c;
}`

Then iterate with a 
`foreach(var child in Model.c)` on the View